# How to declare the model that will work with nested object?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, object

I need to create an object that struture like this

```
distances.append([
    "distanceInMiles":String(distanceInMiles),
    "distanceInMeters":String(distanceInMeters),
    "places": [
        {
            "name":nameI,
            "city":cityI,
            "lat":latitudeI,
            "lon":longitudeI,
            "coordinate":coordinateI
        }, {
            "name":nameJ,
            "city":cityJ,
            "lat":latitudeJ,
            "lon":longitudeJ,
            "coordinate":coordinateJ
        }
    ]
])
```

What should my variable declaration be?

I've tried

```
var distances = [ Dictionary<String,String>()]
```

I got

> Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: Make your life more convenient and use custom structs/classes.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is. Can you clarify exactly what you are struggling with? Are you not sure how to create the `init()` method for this object?

Comment: @vadian https://i.imgur.com/nUZq2pM.png  like this ?

Comment: Almost: `distanceIn...` can be the original type (`Int` or `Double`), `places` can be non-optional and **must** be an array `[Place]`, and all struct members can be constants (`let`).

Comment: Another thing you can do to make your code look cleaner is to have a setter method for your `distanceInMiles` and `distanceInMeters` properties, that way if you set one of them, the other is automatically set as well.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? it feels like the only thing you need are the name & coordinates of the two places. Everything else can be computed from that info

Comment: Your declaration and initialization should be `var distances = [[String:String]]()`. You have the `()` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a struct/class for such a complex structure:

```
struct Distance { // You might want to find a better name
    let distanceInMiles: Double
    let distanceInMeters: Double
    let places: [Place]
}

struct Place {
    let name: String
    let city: String
    let lat: Double
    let long: Double
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D // You might want to make this a computed property instead
}
```

And then you can create a `Distance` array:

```
var distances = [Distance]()
distance.append(Distance(
    distanceInMiles: distanceInMiles,
    distanceInMeters: distanceInMeters,
    places: [
        Place(name: nameI, city: cityI, lat: latitudeI, long: longitudeI, coordinate: coordinateI),
        Place(name: nameJ, city: cityJ, lat: latitudeJ, long: longitudeJ, coordinate: coordinateJ),
    ]
))
```

As you can see, the aesthetic is very similar to your JSON-like structure.

By the way, if you plan on converting this structure to JSON and send it to somewhere, you can make both structs conform to `Codable`.

Comment: You're my hero ! 

Comment: I only see 1 issue, I got `Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocation' to expected argument type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'` https://i.imgur.com/IBALwcE.png

Comment: @kyo There is a property called [`coordinate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423504-coordinate) in `CLLocation`. Use that: `coordinateI.coordinate`. Alternatively, remove the `coordinate` property altogether since you can get it from `lat` and `long`, can't you?

Comment: @kyo Or, make the `coordinate` property in your struct of type `CLLocation`.